# Script to open a chrome extension URL

Tags: google-chrome, script

I want to be able to create a keyboard shortcut to Dewey (a Chrome extension for bookmark management) using BetterTouchTool. BetterTouch tools allow opening urls, but if I try entering the URL "chrome-extension://aahpfefkmihhdabllidnlipghcjgpkdm/app.html#/main", it opens "file:///chrome-extension://aahpfefkmihhdabllidnlipghcjgpkdm/app.html#/main" instead. So I'd like to create a script that will launch this URL. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a little trick. You already know that you can open local files using `file:` pseudoprotocol, so you can create a HTML file that will instantly redirect to the extension page. Save that file in some unobtrusive location and use it as a target.

Here's the HTML code that will instantly redirect to your URL when opened:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='chrome-extension://aahpfefkmihhdabllidnlipghcjgpkdm/app.html#/main'">
    </head>
</html>
```

Paste it into any text editor and save with `.html` extension. Code doesn't have to be indented, you could put all that stuff in a single like but I split it to make selecting a bit more convenient.

Now you have to figure out `file:` URI for your HTML document. To do that, you have to prepend its absolute path with `file:///`.

For example if you have saved the file as `/my/home/folder/chrome-redirect.html`, then your URI will be `file:///my/home/folder/chrome-redirect.html`.

Verify if the URI works by pasting it into Chrome's address bar - you should be instantly redirected to the extension URI. If it works, then you can use it in BetterTouchTool.

<sub>(trick tested on Chrome 38 dev on Windows)</sub>

Comment: this not work for chromium 68, it redirects to blank tab on win7